# Nested object structure in json format

Tags: python, json

The json structure

```
{
    "categories": [{
        "supercategory": "Bottle",
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bottle"
    },
    {
        "supercategory": "Car",
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Car"
    }]
}
```

Is read by the following python script:

```
with open('file.json') as json_data:
    json_info = json.load(json_data)
```

At some later point, the same script tries to access the data structure in the following way:

```
json_info['1']['name']
json_info['2']['name']
```

Where the numbers refer to the "id" field in the json structure. Since that code is obviously inconsistent with the json structure: How do I have to change the json structure to make that work? (Assuming I can't change the script).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your code to work, you'll need something like this:

```
json_info = {
     "1": {"supercategory": "Bottle",
           "name": "Bottle"},
     "2": {"supercategory": "Car",
           "name": "Car"}
     }
```

Comment: You out clicked me, my friend!  But, you did win fair and square by 41 seconds, have an upvote!

Comment: @AaronN.Brock Thanks, upvoted you as soon as you posted :)

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
{
    "1": {
        "supercategory": "Bottle",
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bottle"
    },
    "2": {
        "supercategory": "Car",
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Car"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firsty, I would highly recommend using the 'get' method whenever accessing a dictionary in Python. It implicitly handles cases in which the given key(s) are not valid and prevents errors by returning null (or a default value). See this [link](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/not_using_get_to_return_a_default_value_from_a_dictionary.html) for more info. So the code would be re-written as `json_info.get('1',{}).get('name')`. Note the default empty dictionary in the first get - this is to avoid None type errors.
Second, if indeed you mean to access objects by their ID STRING (and not int) your JSON data structure would be:

```
{
  "1": {
    "supercategory": "Bottle",
    "name": "Bottle"
  },
  "2": {
    "supercategory": "Car",
    "name": "Car"
  }
}
```